# How to Unpivot this table?

Tags: plsql, unpivot

[Base table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLfJM.png)

I have been trying out unpivot but to no avail. My desired output should be:
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGswt.png)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, you need to ***unpivot*** your intial data in order to get rows per month and per another new column containing values for both columns A and B.
- Then, you can easily ***pivot*** the resulting data to get the desired output format.

```sql
WITH Your_test_cases (MONTH, a, b) AS (
SELECT 
  to_char(add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), LEVEL - 1), 'FMMONTH', 'nls_date_language=ENGLISH') MONTH
, LEVEL a
, LEVEL b
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
)
SELECT *
FROM Your_test_cases
UNPIVOT (
VAL_A_AND_B_IN_ONE_COL FOR COL IN (
  A AS 'A'
, B AS 'B'
)
)
PIVOT (
MIN(VAL_A_AND_B_IN_ONE_COL) FOR MONTH IN (
'JANUARY' as JANUARY,
'FEBRUARY' as FEBRUARY,
'MARCH' as MARCH,
'APRIL' as APRIL,
'MAY' as MAY,
'JUNE' as JUNE,
'JULY' as JULY,
'AUGUST' as AUGUST,
'SEPTEMBER' as SEPTEMBER,
'OCTOBER' as OCTOBER,
'NOVEMBER' as NOVEMBER,
'DECEMBER' as DECEMBER
)
)
ORDER BY 1
;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KImIASlc)

Comment: thank you so much! I edited it to suit my needs and it works! wohooo!!